# PHP - Put special characters from a string into another string

Tags: php, preg-match, special-characters

I have a function that I want to tell me what special characters are in a string.

I don't want to strip them I want to put into another variable.

```
if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string)) {
    $special_characters = special characters from $string
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: you want to remove special char?

Comment: actually the opposite I want to leave the special characters and remove everything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = 'sds$%&dd$%&gfhfh';
$string = preg_match_all ('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string, $result);
$output = '';
foreach($result[0] as $r){

$output .= $r;
}

echo $output;
```

Output:  `$%&$%&`

see [live demo](https://eval.in/295758)

Comment: thank you, can't believe I didn't realise there was a matches argument :/

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You practically have it already! Just add the "another variable" as the **matches** argument:

```
if(preg_match_all('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string, $special_characters)) {
  print_r($special_characters);
}
```

Please note that **$special_characters** will be an **array**.

So, for `$string = "$450 is the total cost, which is about 20% of the income.";`, you will have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => $
            [1] => ,
            [2] => %
        )

)
```